# Rendering Partials with Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, slim-lang

Current Slim.html:

```
#fullpage
  =render partial: 'section_one'
  =render partial: 'section_two'
  =render partial: 'section_three'
  =render partial: 'section_four'
  =render partial: 'section_five'
```

The issue I'm having is that I don't want to render partial: 'section_four' is this is being viewed on mobile.

I tried this:

```
#fullpage
  =render partial: 'section_one'
  =render partial: 'section_two'
  =render partial: 'section_three'
  - if $(window).width() >= 700
    =render partial: 'section_four'
  =render partial: 'section_five'
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `request.user_agent` to recognize mobile device. Also you should use inline `if` condition while checking for mobile device:

```
= render partial: 'section_four' if request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
```

There can be some cases where `request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/` will fail to return expected results due to browser's custom user_agent.

So, I recommend [**Mobile-Fu**](https://github.com/benlangfeld/mobile-fu) to work with it in better way.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).width() >= 700` is a javascript code and *you can't do it like this. Apart from using request.user_agent **you can use css media-queries to selectively show or hide content inside your partial***. Lets suppose your partial section_four has content like this:

```
#some_id
  .your_content
```

*now you can **target #some_id by css and show or hide it according to your device width***

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
  #some_id {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

For details check  [**`css media queries`**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)